# Rails - Citier - Two level inheritance, Child Class don't inherit Middle Class attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, citier, multi-table-inheritance

I'm trying to implement a structure like: GrandFather <- Father <- Son
Using rails and the gem citier. This example should create 2 tables to represent the 3 classes: one for the Root class (GrandFather) and it's attributes and other to represent the Father and Son classes (since Son don't have additional attributes) and Father's attributes.

```
class GrandFather < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_citier
    attr_accessible :grand_father_attr, :type
end

class Father < GrandFather
    acts_as_citier
    attr_accessible :father_attr
end

class Son < Father

end

class CreateGrandFathers < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :grand_fathers do |t|
            t.string :type
            t.string :grand_father_attr
            t.timestamps
        end
    end
end

class CreateFathers < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def up
        create_table :fathers do |t|
            t.string :father_attr
        end
        create_citier_view(Father)
    end

    def down
        drop_citier_view(Father)
        drop_table :fathers
    end
end
```

But if I open rails console and type 'Son.new' the attribute from GrandFather is there, but the one from Father class is missing:

```
1.9.3-p362 :001 > Son.new
citier -> Root Class
citier -> table_name -> grand_fathers
citier -> Non Root Class
citier -> table_name -> fathers
citier -> tablename (view) -> view_fathers
   (1.1ms)   SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM pg_tables
 WHERE tablename = 'grand_fathers'


   (0.5ms)   SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM pg_views
 WHERE viewname = 'grand_fathers'

 => #<Son id: nil, type: "Son", grand_father_attr: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a very simple workaround, in my example the only modification would be:

```
class Son < Father 
   acts_as_citier :table_name => 'fathers'
end
```